# Remove hex representations from strings - Python

Tags: python, excel, exception, pdf, openpyxl

Okay, so here's a brief:

**Objective:** Detect that a string contains hex values and either extract them correctly or delete them.

**Problem:** I want to be able to write my strings to an excel sheet using openpyxl without it raising an illegal character exception error.

**Sample Problematic string:**

```
'\xc2\x87,QGLYLGXDO\x03ZLWK\x03EUHDVW\x03FDQFHU\x03\xc2\x9435
```

Or:

```
'5LVN\x03VWDWXV\x1d\x033RRU\x10ULVN\x1e\x03&amp;\\WRJHQHWLFV\x1d\x03&amp;RPSOH[\x03\x0b\xc2\x95\x03\x16\x03FORQDO\x03FKURPRVRPDO\x03DEQRUPDOLWLHV\x0c\x1e\x030RQRVRPDO\x03
```

**What I have tried:** I tried checking for every element before writing, whether it was a valid string, by doing the if `type(element) == str:` or `isinstance(element) == unicode` but to no effect.

How do I solve this issue?

**Extra information:**
*What I did:*

1. Converted PDF files into *xls* format by a freely available software on the internet. [Unfortunately, the software just claims to convert it to xls, when it fact the data gets written in **xml**]
2. Now, I take these xml files and write a *parser* to extract data from it.
3. Third, I use the extracted data and write it to excel sheets using the **openpyxl** package.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the source of openpyxl you'll find the regex responsible for checking whether characters are allowed or not and you can use this to check the strings. It seems `\x03` is the problem. You can either strip or escape these characters from your source.

```
import re
ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE = re.compile(r'[\000-\010]|[\013-\014]|[\016-\037]')
m = ILLEGAL_CHARACTERS_RE.search(s)
m
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(12, 13), match='\x03'>
```

Comment: What if the string is `UHVHFWLRQ◄ QEVS▲♥/RZ♥ULVN♥IHDWXUHV↔        QEVS▲♥2OLJRGHQGURJOLRPD♥RU♥PL[HG` ?

Comment: Then it contains invalid characters that you will need to escape before creating an Excel file.

Comment: How would I be able to do that? From the string in the comment above, I could eliminate special symbols like the 'heart' or the 'triangle', but the garbage string which consists of letters still remains. Could you suggest something? @Charlie Clark

Comment: You could simply use the regex to remove them.

Comment: The main issue is: For example: Let there be two string A and B: A = We have seven continents, and B = the above garbage string. In this case, how would I differentiate between garbage letters and authentic letters? If I write regex expression even the authentic letters would get removed, won't they?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
e = "\x00\x03Rock\x04Is\x09 Cool"
m = re.split('\s+', re.sub(r"[\x00-\x1F\x7F]", ' ', e))        
result = ' '.join(m)
print result
```

Sample Output:

```
RockIsCool
```

The following excluded most of the hexadecimal values except `\x0b` & `\x0c` since they are among the printable characters.

```
e = filter(lambda x: x in string.printable, e)
```